# HTML is read before fully loaded using open-uri and nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm using `open-uri` and `nokogiri` with ruby to do some simple webcrawling.
There's one problem that sometimes html is read before it is fully loaded. In such cases, I cannot fetch any content other than the loading-icon and the nav bar.
What is the best way to tell `open-uri` or `nokogiri` to wait until the page is fully loaded?

Currently my script looks like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://www.the-page-i-wanna-crawl.com"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)) 
puts doc.at_css("h2").text
```

Comment: [example.com](http://example.com) source does not have any <h2> tag.

Comment: It's just a placeholder for my question. Sorry to be misleading.

Comment: Define "fully loaded", what about images, external scripts, ajax content, etc.?

Comment: I mean the main part of the page(a list of blogs) w/o external scripts and ajax content.

Comment: Are you sure what you think is happening is what's happening? I.e., did you check with curl or similar? I've not seen the behavior you describe.

Comment: Yes, I've checked with curl and the body part of the page only shows the loading icon. When I open the page with a browser, I can also see the loading icon, and after about 2 seconds, the content of the body part appears.

Comment: That would suggest that the content is being loaded via AJAX or some other JS method and that the raw HTML source (which is all curl/nokogiri can see) doesn't contain what you want.  In which case you'll need to pick another scraper that is JS/ajax aware.

Comment: Or, find out the AJAX URL for the content you want and request that directly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you describe is not possible. The result of `open` will only be passed to `HTML` after the `open` method as returned the full value.

I suspect that the page itself uses AJAX to load its content, as has been suggested in the comments, in this case you may use Watir to fetch the page using a browser

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'https://www.the-page-i-wanna-crawl.com'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
```

This might open a browser window though.

Comment: It's pretty handy. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid browser opening?

Comment: @lcguida browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true