# Using Nokogiri I am unable to find certain nodes in a document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

When trying to search a document for `ysr-bio-data` ("Height" value) on this page http://sports.yahoo.com/footballrecruiting/football/recruiting/player-Jonathan-Allen-125805

The node is nil.  Is this because nokogiri is getting the page before this section is populated? Or is it that the nokogiri object isn't storing the whole page into it's object?
Below is some sample code of how I'm trying to retrieve the data.  Thanks!

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://sports.yahoo.com/footballrecruiting/football/recruiting/player-Jonathan-Allen-125805'))

doc.css('ul#ysr-bio-data')
```

If I need to provide any additional information please let me know. Thanks!

Edit: Fixed incorrect syntax.

Comment: `doc.css('ul#ysr-bio-data')`

Comment: use just `doc.css('#ysr-bio-data')` form.

Comment: @majioa, my apologies I used the quotes in my code just didn't copy over correctly.  With the quotes I still do not get a node object back. thanks!

Comment: and with quotes but without `ul`?

Comment: @majioa, yes tried both.  I was able to solve it with the answer i provided. the information was being supplied with ajax or something.  So I needed a way to load the data into memory first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry bud, but there is javascript that needs to run on the page for those cells to be filled out.

you can do this tho.. make the javascript run in a web-browser..

```
require 'nokogiri' 
require 'watir-webdriver' #http://watir.com/

$browser = Watir::Browser.start "http://sports.yahoo.com/footballrecruiting/football/recruiting/player-Jonathan-Allen-125805"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html)

doc.css("ul#ysr-bio-data").text
=>  "Ht:6'3\"Wt:263 lbs40:4.5 secsBench Max:280Class:2013 (High School)\t"
```

We're basically replacing open-uri with watir.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found another question on stackoverflow that provided a means to solving my issue.

[HTML is read before fully loaded using open-uri and nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789583/html-is-read-before-fully-loaded-using-open-uri-and-nokogiri)