# How to get all elements via CSS class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape [this](http://www.straight.com/listings/events?search=&starting[value]&timing=All&cat=All&page=0) page using Nokogiri to get all the elements with class name of "teaser".

If I check the page with jQuery, I can see there are 25 elements:

```
$(".teaser").length => 25
```

However, when using Nokogiri, I only get the first teaser:

```
teasers = doc.css('.teaser')
teasers.count => 1
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I get all the teasers?

Comment: If you see output of "doc.to_html" , You will get only one teaser element.

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789583/html-is-read-before-fully-loaded-using-open-uri-and-nokogiri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document appears to have a load of null bytes in it for some reason, and this is causing Nokogiri/LibXML to assume the document has finished part way through.

You should be able to fix it by preprocessing the contents to remove the nulls. If `page` contains the text of the webpage:

```
page.gsub! /\x00/, ''
```

Then use Nokogiri on `page` as before.